# Flex VideoDisplay reconnect after idletimeout

Tags: apache-flex, videodisplay, reconnect, idle-processing

I have a VideoDisplay that is able to connect to a source and play.  After the connection times out I want the connection to be re-established when my play button is clicked.  Right now when I reset the source and play the videoDisplay, it gets stuck in the loading state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to set source to null then back to your intended source and call load() then set the playhead position